# What is the probability that the sum of a subset of drawn integers without replacement does not exceed a certain threshold?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have the following combinatoric problem to solve; I have searched and couldn't find an answer already existing.

In the main lottery in Germany, 6 numbers are to be drawn out of $49$ $\{1,2,\ldots49\}$ without replacement.

What is the probability that the sum of the 3 lowest drawn numbers is below a certain value, say $z=30$ for example?

In the end, I do not really want the probability, but the number z, so that the probability amounts to roughly $25\%$ $(75\%)$ by construction.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are $n=\frac{49!}{43!}$ways of choosing the 6 numbers.  You need to enumerate the number of ways of choosing $6$ numbers such that the least 3 add up to no more than $z$ and divide by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

We just have to count how many $6$-subsets satisfy that the sum of their three smallest integers is less than $z$, and divide this by $\binom{49}{6}$. We can do this easily with a computer.

Here is some c++ code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int A[6];// we use this array to iterate over all 6-subsets
int S[200];// S[i] stores the number of 6-subsets adding to i
int tot=0;// the total number of 6-subsets

int push(){// this just takes us to the next 6-set
    for(int i=5;i>=0;i--){
        if(A[i]+5-i<49){
            A[i]++;
            for(int j=i+1;j<6;j++){
                A[j]=A[j-1]+1;
            }
            return(1);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){// the first set is 1,2,3,4,5,6
        A[i]=i+1;
    }
    while(!tot || push()){// while we haven't reached the final set
        tot++;// add one to tot
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){// find the sum of the smallest three elements
            sum+=A[i];
        }
        S[sum]++;// add one to the number of sets adding to sum
    }
    double acc=0;
    for(int i=5;i<=132;i++){// print the results
        acc+=S[i];
        printf("If $z=%d$ the probability is: $%f$ \n\n",i+1,acc/tot);
    }
}
```

The results:

If $z=6$ the probability is: $0.000000$

If $z=7$ the probability is: $0.001086$

If $z=8$ the probability is: $0.002100$

If $z=9$ the probability is: $0.004062$

If $z=10$ the probability is: $0.006906$

If $z=11$ the probability is: $0.010504$

If $z=12$ the probability is: $0.014800$

If $z=13$ the probability is: $0.020622$

If $z=14$ the probability is: $0.026914$

If $z=15$ the probability is: $0.034454$

If $z=16$ the probability is: $0.043144$

If $z=17$ the probability is: $0.052773$

If $z=18$ the probability is: $0.063257$

If $z=19$ the probability is: $0.075228$

If $z=20$ the probability is: $0.087738$

If $z=21$ the probability is: $0.101383$

If $z=22$ the probability is: $0.116056$

If $z=23$ the probability is: $0.131501$

If $z=24$ the probability is: $0.147632$

If $z=25$ the probability is: $0.164927$

If $z=26$ the probability is: $0.182563$

If $z=27$ the probability is: $0.200993$

If $z=28$ the probability is: $0.220124$

If $z=29$ the probability is: $0.239684$

If $z=30$ the probability is: $0.259603$

If $z=31$ the probability is: $0.280246$

If $z=32$ the probability is: $0.300916$

If $z=33$ the probability is: $0.321964$

If $z=34$ the probability is: $0.343321$

If $z=35$ the probability is: $0.364724$

If $z=36$ the probability is: $0.386130$

If $z=37$ the probability is: $0.407823$

If $z=38$ the probability is: $0.429230$

If $z=39$ the probability is: $0.450628$

If $z=40$ the probability is: $0.471982$

If $z=41$ the probability is: $0.493052$

If $z=42$ the probability is: $0.513827$

If $z=43$ the probability is: $0.534535$

If $z=44$ the probability is: $0.554720$

If $z=45$ the probability is: $0.574607$

If $z=46$ the probability is: $0.594192$

If $z=47$ the probability is: $0.613272$

If $z=48$ the probability is: $0.631864$

If $z=49$ the probability is: $0.650156$

If $z=50$ the probability is: $0.667796$

If $z=51$ the probability is: $0.684970$

If $z=52$ the probability is: $0.701703$

If $z=53$ the probability is: $0.717826$

If $z=54$ the probability is: $0.733380$

If $z=55$ the probability is: $0.748519$

If $z=56$ the probability is: $0.762980$

If $z=57$ the probability is: $0.776915$

If $z=58$ the probability is: $0.790367$

If $z=59$ the probability is: $0.803198$

If $z=60$ the probability is: $0.815465$

If $z=61$ the probability is: $0.827291$

If $z=62$ the probability is: $0.838483$

If $z=63$ the probability is: $0.849165$

If $z=64$ the probability is: $0.859388$

If $z=65$ the probability is: $0.869044$

If $z=66$ the probability is: $0.878192$

If $z=67$ the probability is: $0.886933$

If $z=68$ the probability is: $0.895127$

If $z=69$ the probability is: $0.902872$

If $z=70$ the probability is: $0.910225$

If $z=71$ the probability is: $0.917097$

If $z=72$ the probability is: $0.923550$

If $z=73$ the probability is: $0.929660$

If $z=74$ the probability is: $0.935331$

If $z=75$ the probability is: $0.940639$

If $z=76$ the probability is: $0.945636$

If $z=77$ the probability is: $0.950255$

If $z=78$ the probability is: $0.954552$

If $z=79$ the probability is: $0.958585$

If $z=80$ the probability is: $0.962287$

If $z=81$ the probability is: $0.965717$

If $z=82$ the probability is: $0.968920$

If $z=83$ the probability is: $0.971844$

If $z=84$ the probability is: $0.974538$

If $z=85$ the probability is: $0.977045$

If $z=86$ the probability is: $0.979318$

If $z=87$ the probability is: $0.981402$

If $z=88$ the probability is: $0.983332$

If $z=89$ the probability is: $0.985072$

If $z=90$ the probability is: $0.986657$

If $z=91$ the probability is: $0.988120$

If $z=92$ the probability is: $0.989429$

If $z=93$ the probability is: $0.990615$

If $z=94$ the probability is: $0.991704$

If $z=95$ the probability is: $0.992672$

If $z=96$ the probability is: $0.993543$

If $z=97$ the probability is: $0.994339$

If $z=98$ the probability is: $0.995040$

If $z=99$ the probability is: $0.995667$

If $z=100$ the probability is: $0.996238$

If $z=101$ the probability is: $0.996734$

If $z=102$ the probability is: $0.997175$

If $z=103$ the probability is: $0.997574$

If $z=104$ the probability is: $0.997917$

If $z=105$ the probability is: $0.998218$

If $z=106$ the probability is: $0.998489$

If $z=107$ the probability is: $0.998719$

If $z=108$ the probability is: $0.998919$

If $z=109$ the probability is: $0.999097$

If $z=110$ the probability is: $0.999246$

If $z=111$ the probability is: $0.999373$

If $z=112$ the probability is: $0.999487$

If $z=113$ the probability is: $0.999579$

If $z=114$ the probability is: $0.999657$

If $z=115$ the probability is: $0.999725$

If $z=116$ the probability is: $0.999779$

If $z=117$ the probability is: $0.999824$

If $z=118$ the probability is: $0.999863$

If $z=119$ the probability is: $0.999893$

If $z=120$ the probability is: $0.999917$

If $z=121$ the probability is: $0.999938$

If $z=122$ the probability is: $0.999954$

If $z=123$ the probability is: $0.999965$

If $z=124$ the probability is: $0.999976$

If $z=125$ the probability is: $0.999982$

If $z=126$ the probability is: $0.999988$

If $z=127$ the probability is: $0.999992$

If $z=128$ the probability is: $0.999995$

If $z=129$ the probability is: $0.999996$

If $z=130$ the probability is: $0.999998$

If $z=131$ the probability is: $0.999999$

If $z=132$ the probability is: $0.999999$

If $z=133$ the probability is: $1.000000$

Comment: It's $\binom{49}{6}$ rather than $50$.

Comment: You're right thanks, luckily I Made no mistake in the code. Fixed.

Comment: In case that's not clear for the OP, the answer is that $30$ is the smallest $z$ for which the probability that the sum of the least 3 numbers is less than $z$, is at least 25%